# Why does requesting GPUs as a generic resource on a cluster running SLURM with the built-in plugin fail?

Tags: cluster, hpc, job-scheduler

*Disclaimer: This post is quite long as I tried to provide all relevant configuration information.*

## Status and Problem:

I adminster a gpu cluster and I want to use slurm for job management.
Unfortunatelly, I cannot request GPUs using the respective generic resources plugin of slurm.

*Note: test.sh is a small script printing the environment variable CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES.*

#### Running job with `--gres=gpu:1` does not complete

Running `srun -n1 --gres=gpu:1 test.sh` results in the following error:

```
srun: error: Unable to allocate resources: Requested node configuration is not available
```

*Log:*

```
gres: gpu state for job 83
    gres_cnt:4 node_cnt:0 type:(null)
    _pick_best_nodes: job 83 never runnable
    _slurm_rpc_allocate_resources: Requested node configuration is not available
```

#### Running job with `--gres=gram:500` does complete

If I call `srun -n1 --gres=gram:500 test.sh` however, the job runs and prints

```
CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=NoDevFiles
```

*Log:*

```
sched: _slurm_rpc_allocate_resources JobId=76 NodeList=smurf01 usec=193
debug:  Configuration for job 76 complete
debug:  laying out the 1 tasks on 1 hosts smurf01 dist 1
job_complete: JobID=76 State=0x1 NodeCnt=1 WIFEXITED 1 WEXITSTATUS 0
job_complete: JobID=76 State=0x8003 NodeCnt=1 done
```

**Thus slurm seems to be correctly configured to run jobs using `srun` with requested generic resources using `--gres` but does not recognize the gpus for some reason.**

*My first idea was to use another name for the gpu generic resource as the other generic resources seem to work but I'd like to stick to the gpu plugin.*

## Configuration

The cluster has more than two slave hosts but for the sake of clarity i'll stick to two slightly differently configured slave hosts and the controller host: papa (controller), smurf01 and smurf02.´

### slurm.conf

The generic-resrouce-relevant parts of the slurm configuration:

```
...
TaskPlugin=task/cgroup
...
GresTypes=gpu,ram,gram,scratch
...
NodeName=smurf01 NodeAddr=192.168.1.101 Feature="intel,fermi" Boards=1 SocketsPerBoard=2 CoresPerSocket=6 ThreadsPerCore=2 Gres=gpu:tesla:8,ram:48,gram:no_consume:6000,scratch:1300
NodeName=smurf02 NodeAddr=192.168.1.102 Feature="intel,fermi" Boards=1 SocketsPerBoard=2 CoresPerSocket=6 ThreadsPerCore=1 Gres=gpu:tesla:8,ram:48,gram:no_consume:6000,scratch:1300
...
```

*Note: ram is in GB, gram is in MB and scratch in GB again.*

### Output of `scontrol show node`

```
NodeName=smurf01 Arch=x86_64 CoresPerSocket=6
   CPUAlloc=0 CPUErr=0 CPUTot=24 CPULoad=0.01 Features=intel,fermi
   Gres=gpu:tesla:8,ram:48,gram:no_consume:6000,scratch:1300
   NodeAddr=192.168.1.101 NodeHostName=smurf01 Version=14.11
   OS=Linux RealMemory=1 AllocMem=0 Sockets=2 Boards=1
   State=IDLE ThreadsPerCore=2 TmpDisk=0 Weight=1
   BootTime=2015-04-23T13:58:15 SlurmdStartTime=2015-04-24T10:30:46
   CurrentWatts=0 LowestJoules=0 ConsumedJoules=0
   ExtSensorsJoules=n/s ExtSensorsWatts=0 ExtSensorsTemp=n/s

NodeName=smurf02 Arch=x86_64 CoresPerSocket=6
   CPUAlloc=0 CPUErr=0 CPUTot=12 CPULoad=0.01 Features=intel,fermi
   Gres=gpu:tesla:8,ram:48,gram:no_consume:6000,scratch:1300
   NodeAddr=192.168.1.102 NodeHostName=smurf02 Version=14.11
   OS=Linux RealMemory=1 AllocMem=0 Sockets=2 Boards=1
   State=IDLE ThreadsPerCore=1 TmpDisk=0 Weight=1
   BootTime=2015-04-23T13:57:56 SlurmdStartTime=2015-04-24T10:24:12
   CurrentWatts=0 LowestJoules=0 ConsumedJoules=0
   ExtSensorsJoules=n/s ExtSensorsWatts=0 ExtSensorsTemp=n/s
```

### smurf01 configuration

#### GPUs

```
 > ls /dev | grep nvidia
nvidia0
... 
nvidia7
 > nvidia-smi | grep Tesla
|   0  Tesla M2090         On   | 0000:08:00.0     Off |                    0 |
... 
|   7  Tesla M2090         On   | 0000:1B:00.0     Off |                    0 |
...
```

#### gres.conf

```
Name=gpu Type=tesla File=/dev/nvidia0 CPUs=0
Name=gpu Type=tesla File=/dev/nvidia1 CPUs=1
Name=gpu Type=tesla File=/dev/nvidia2 CPUs=2
Name=gpu Type=tesla File=/dev/nvidia3 CPUs=3
Name=gpu Type=tesla File=/dev/nvidia4 CPUs=4
Name=gpu Type=tesla File=/dev/nvidia5 CPUs=5
Name=gpu Type=tesla File=/dev/nvidia6 CPUs=6
Name=gpu Type=tesla File=/dev/nvidia7 CPUs=7
Name=ram Count=48
Name=gram Count=6000
Name=scratch Count=1300
```

### smurf02 configuration

#### GPUs

Same configuration/output as smurf01.

#### gres.conf on smurf02

```
Name=gpu Count=8 Type=tesla File=/dev/nvidia[0-7]
Name=ram Count=48
Name=gram Count=6000
Name=scratch Count=1300
```

*Note: The deamons have been restarted, the machines have been rebooted as well. The slurm and job submitting user have same ids/groups on slave and controller nodes and the munge authentication is working properly.*

## Log outputs

I added `DebugFlags=Gres` in the slurm.conf file and the GPUs seem to be recognized by the Plugin:

### Controller log

```
gres / gpu: state for smurf01
   gres_cnt found : 8 configured : 8 avail : 8 alloc : 0
   gres_bit_alloc :
   gres_used : (null)
   topo_cpus_bitmap[0] : 0
   topo_gres_bitmap[0] : 0
   topo_gres_cnt_alloc[0] : 0
   topo_gres_cnt_avail[0] : 1
   type[0] : tesla
   topo_cpus_bitmap[1] : 1
   topo_gres_bitmap[1] : 1
   topo_gres_cnt_alloc[1] : 0
   topo_gres_cnt_avail[1] : 1
   type[1] : tesla
   topo_cpus_bitmap[2] : 2
   topo_gres_bitmap[2] : 2
   topo_gres_cnt_alloc[2] : 0
   topo_gres_cnt_avail[2] : 1
   type[2] : tesla
   topo_cpus_bitmap[3] : 3
   topo_gres_bitmap[3] : 3
   topo_gres_cnt_alloc[3] : 0
   topo_gres_cnt_avail[3] : 1
   type[3] : tesla
   topo_cpus_bitmap[4] : 4
   topo_gres_bitmap[4] : 4
   topo_gres_cnt_alloc[4] : 0
   topo_gres_cnt_avail[4] : 1
   type[4] : tesla
   topo_cpus_bitmap[5] : 5
   topo_gres_bitmap[5] : 5
   topo_gres_cnt_alloc[5] : 0
   topo_gres_cnt_avail[5] : 1
   type[5] : tesla
   topo_cpus_bitmap[6] : 6
   topo_gres_bitmap[6] : 6
   topo_gres_cnt_alloc[6] : 0
   topo_gres_cnt_avail[6] : 1
   type[6] : tesla
   topo_cpus_bitmap[7] : 7
   topo_gres_bitmap[7] : 7
   topo_gres_cnt_alloc[7] : 0
   topo_gres_cnt_avail[7] : 1
   type[7] : tesla
   type_cnt_alloc[0] : 0
   type_cnt_avail[0] : 8
   type[0] : tesla
...
gres/gpu: state for smurf02
   gres_cnt found:TBD configured:8 avail:8 alloc:0
   gres_bit_alloc:
   gres_used:(null)
   type_cnt_alloc[0]:0
   type_cnt_avail[0]:8
   type[0]:tesla
```

### Slave log

```
Gres Name = gpu Type = tesla Count = 8 ID = 7696487 File = / dev / nvidia[0 - 7]
...
gpu 0 is device number 0
gpu 1 is device number 1
gpu 2 is device number 2
gpu 3 is device number 3
gpu 4 is device number 4
gpu 5 is device number 5
gpu 6 is device number 6
gpu 7 is device number 7
```

Comment: What happens if you request ``--gres=gpu:tesla:1``?

Comment: @NMWizard The very same as without a specified type.

Answer (score 1):

Slurm in the installed Version (`14.11.5`) seems to have problems with types assigned to the GPUs since removing `Type=...` from the `gres.conf` and changing the node configuration lines accordingly (to `Gres=gpu:N,ram:...`) results in successful execution of jobs requiring gpus via `--gres=gpu:N`.